# React Native Expo published app not displaying logo properly

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, google-play, google-play-console

I published an app on Google Play. Everywhere the logo is fine, but when I install app on physical device from Google Play, it does not show the full logo of my app. Weird behaviour, kind of like it zooms in, cuts off the edges.
I suspect it's something to do with my app.json, I tried with a bunch of image sizes, maybe I am not trying correct ones.

```
"icon": "./192.png",
"android": {
  "adaptiveIcon": {
    "foregroundImage": "./Icon.png",
    "backgroundImage": "./BG.png"
},
```

This is the latest code I tried.
192.png is basically 192 x 192 image.
Icon.png is the icon image by itself (not including the background of the icon).
BG.png is the background color of the image.

[How I expected it to show up once installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euaHJ.png)
[How it shows up once installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MKTV.png)

I tried using 512 x 512 png image in the icon field as well, but that did not work either.

Comment: I don't experience this when using the `icon` field, but I'm not certain about `adaptiveIcon`

Comment: What do you do that works for your icons?
Earlier I published another app, that app also had the same problem, even though not as bad as this one.

Comment: Just don't use the `adaptiveIcon` field. Use `icon` at the top level of the config.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add the path from assets properly in app.json for icon,

like

```
"icon": "./assetsPath/example.png",
"android": {
  "adaptiveIcon": {
    "foregroundImage": "./assetsPath/example.png",
    "backgroundImage": "./assetsPath/example.png"
},
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNs5Q.png)

Comment: I have the images in the root of the project.
Where the App.js is, it isn't a path issue, since logo is showing up in the 1st place.

Answer (score 0):

On android app icon zoom into center a little so Expo has a app icon and splash screen guide about it.You can fit your app into through this template it will be alright.

https://www.figma.com/community/file/1155362909441341285